# change Listpicker fullscreen mode done and cancel icons image URI

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-toolkit, windows-phone

I have a listpicker and I set selectionmode="multiple". When I tap the listpicker it shows the list. but at the bottom, Application bar appear with done and cancel icons.How to change the image uri of those icons? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to change the icon uris? You can just change the image files if that is what you wanted in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't.

But, the source code for the listpicker is on codeplex, so you can hack it to your liking.

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888